# Displaying search results from SQL database on React front-end (with Flask)

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm very new to React and Flask. I'm trying to build a form in react that allows users to search a person in a SQL database, using a Flask framework. I have different parts but am not sure how to let the user input a search term - any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

So far my app.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)
port = 5000

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    database='database',
    user='*****',
    password='*****',
)


@app.get('/person')
def get_person(search_term):
    name_input = search_term
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("""SELECT name, date_of_birth, nationality, information FROM person_list WHERE ((SOUNDEX(%s) = SOUNDEX(name)) OR (names LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')));""", (name_input, name_input))
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    response = jsonify(results)
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response

app.run(port=port)
```

In my React project, I have an api.ts file to connect to the backend:

```
export async function getPerson() {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/person");
    return await response.json();
}
```

The search form looks like this:

```
function Search(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div id="search">
            <header>
                <h1>Search Person</h1>
            </header>
            <div className="tab-container">
                    <ul className="tabs">
                        <a className="active">PERSON</a>
                    </ul>
                <div className="tab-content">
                    <div id="tabf0-1">
                            <form>
                                <div>
                                    <label >Name*</label>
                                    <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                                    <i className="fas fa-exclamation-circle failure-icon"></i>
                                    <i className="far fa-check-circle success-icon"></i>
                                    <div className="error"></div>
                                    {/* Add for="dob"*/}
                                    <label>Date of Birth (optional)</label>
                                    <i className="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                                    <input type="dob" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY"/>
                                    <i className="fas fa-exclamation-circle failure-icon"></i>
                                    <i className="far fa-check-circle success-icon"></i>
                                    <div className="error"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" id="submit">Search</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

In the PersonCard.tsx component:

```
import Person from '../models/Person';

function PersonCard({id, name, nationality, information}: Person) {
  return (
  <div className="card mt-3">
    <div className="card-body">
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{id}</p>
      <p>{nationality}</p>
      <p>{information}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default PersonCard;
```

And finally in People.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getPerson } from '../api/api';
import PersonCard from '../components/PersonCard';
import Person from '../models/Person';

function People() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<Person[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(function() {
    getPerson().then(data => setPeople(data));
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <main className="container pt-6 py-4">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h1 className="display-4">Users</h1>
          {people === null
            ? 'Loading...'
            : people.map(person => <PersonCard id={person.id} names={person.names} nationality={person.nationality} information={person.information} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default People;
```

How do I get the user input from the form to app.py in order to search the database?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click on the search button from front end get the value entered in the field.
Then make the API request.
Then pass the data to the PersonCard component through props.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).